# How can I get the name of function from StoreInst's Value In LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I have a structure and it has a pointer to function as follows.

```
typedef struct
{
    void (*p)();
    int n;
} myStruct;
```

I used it as folllowing:

```
myStruct * a = malloc( sizeof(myStruct));
a->n=88;
a->p = &booooo;

a->p()
```

In LLVM, How can I get the name of **function** (booooo) and struct element (a->p) to save it in symbol table and print it later.
I could find the name of the function in StoreInst. 
When I print its value I got this result:

```
void (...)* bitcast (void ()* @booooo to void (...)*)
```

How can I get only the name (booooo) from the value.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two kinds of casts in LLVM IR: BitCastInst and bitcast values.  You have the later.  Fortunately, there is a method for retrieving the original value within the bitcast: `stripPointerCasts()`.  It took me sometime to figure out this distinction.

Here is my usage of the routine, where I was trying to identify the function called (`BasicBlock::iterator I`):

```
if (CallInst *ci = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&*I)) {
    Function *f = ci->getCalledFunction();

    if (f == NULL) 
    { 
        Value* v = ci->getCalledValue();
        f = dyn_cast<Function>(v->stripPointerCasts());
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            continue; 
        }
    }

    const char* fname = f->getName().data();
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the previous question asking the same thing [marginally different], you are better off using the AST form that the Clang compiler produces, rather than the LLVM IR form. It is a much more direct representation of the C or C++ code than the LLVM IR, and easier to work with in general.

But from the `StoreInst` you can use `getValueOperand` to get the value that is being stored, and then `getName` of the value. Of course, like I also said in comments the previous answer, it's not very hard to make the code hard to derive what the original value stored was.

In otherwords, if we have an `llvm::Instruction *inst`, we could do this:

```
if (llvm::StoreInst* si = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::StoreInst>(inst))
{
    std::string name = si->getValueOperand()->getName();
}
```

[Code is not tested, not compiled, no guarantee provided, I just wrote it as part of this answer with the intention that it may work]

Comment: I tested it, and there was no output. I tried Brian's solution and it worked.